# не работает: multiple statements found while compiling a single statement

Tags: python, python-3.x, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Не работает мой код, ошибка в начале multiple statements found while compiling a single statement.

```
import vk_api;
from vk_api.keyboard import VkKeyboard, VkKeyboardColor;
from vk_api.utils import get_random_id;
vk_session = vk_api.VkApi(token='');
vk = vk_session.get_api();
keyboard = VkKeyboard(one_time=True);
keyboard.add_button('Белая кнопка', color=VkKeyboardColor.DEFAULT);
keyboard.add_button('Зелёная кнопка', color=VkKeyboardColor.POSITIVE);
```

Comment: И давно в Python в конце строк ставится точка с запятой?

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev она может там ставиться, и в этом нет ничего плохого ;)

Comment: @Евгений есть плохое. Это нарушает и PEP8, и PEP20.